# Computer struggles to POST but is fine if it does POST

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard

I have a computer with a ROG STRIX B450-F Gaming Motherboard.
It intermittently struggles to POST, it doesn't reach the BIOS and I cannot turn it off without pulling the plug.

When the computer does POST and reach the BIOS, everything works fine. I can play games and use it as normal.

The trouble started when I couldn't get a visual signal from my PC. My monitor's Power and HDMI cable were faulty and were replaced but I did a few hard resets before I figured that out.
I worry this had fried the BIOS/CMOS/RAM/Motherboard in some way.

I have tried removing hard drives,
restarting without any perhipherals plugged in,
cleaned and changed my RAM around,
and rest the CMOS.
Nothing had worked.

I have read before that faulty RAM can cause this but when my computer does boot is runs fine.
I did notice that the manual says that there should be some sort of cap over the CMOS pins but I can't remember seeing it and all other caps on ebay are for shorting the CMOS.

Should I replace my Motherboard and/or RAM or is there something else I've missed?

Comment: reseat everything on the motherboard.  RAM, CPU, Cards, etc...

Comment: *something else I've missed* ... CPU, GPU, PSU - what CPU do you have by the way ... I've seen many videos where the culprit is a faulty Ryzen CPU - though, not many are intermittent faults like yours. It's too bad this mobo doesn't have ANY form of POST indicators, not even simple LEDs to at least point to a possible issue

Comment: This is  usually caused by damaged components that malfunction when cold. Once you have powered it for a while, they heat up and the malfunction disappears. Damaged tracks which have a cut when cold separate with a gap and it's not until they heat up, expand and make contact that they work. This would be at the chip level.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I did reset everything I could and it still didn't seem to work properly. So I thought I would have to buy a new motherboard but I think Bib was right. Now I've run it for a while (avoiding turning it off when it does boot) it seems to work fine! Even the overclocking that I removed with a CMOS reset is back. I literally cannot explain it. 

I guess my PC had a funny 5 minutes for something!